# O que é Ellipsis no Python?

Tags: python, python-internals

Na [lista de constantes nativas](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/constants.html) do Python, pode-se encontrar `Ellipsis`.

```
print(Ellipsis, type(Ellipsis)) #-> (Ellipsis, <type 'ellipsis'>)
```

No Python 3, ainda existe o *açúcar sintático* `...` que representa a constante `Ellipsis`.

```
print(..., type(...)) #-> (Ellipsis, <type 'ellipsis'>)
print(... is Ellipsis) #-> True
```

Então,

- Qual a função da constante `Ellipsis`?
- Quais problemas podem ser resolvidos utilizando a `Ellipsis`?
- Se possível, pode citar um exemplo funcional da sua utilização?

Comment: "Ellipsis" vem do grego, quer dizer "omissão". É usado como um tipo de informação faltosa/omitida, em contraponto a parábola (a informação perfeita, sem sobrar nem faltar) e "hipérbole" (informação sobrando que não seria necessária naquele contexto)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado nessa filosofia, vi que as vezes a ellipsis é utilizada no lugar do `pass` para omitir a definição de uma função: `def foo(): ...`. Isso resulta em uma expressão válida e deixa mais explícito que *algo* foi omitido que a própria utilização do `pass` ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/BpUf4Y)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis), você vai encontrar algo como:

> *The same as `...`. Special value used mostly in conjunction with extended slicing syntax for user-defined container data types.*

Traduzindo livremente:

> O mesmo que `...`. Valor especial usado principalmente em conjunto com a sintaxe de *slice* prolongado para tipos de dados de contêiner definidos pelo usuário.

Eu não conheço nenhum exemplo usado em código puro. Geralmente uso [`Ellipsis` quando escrevo `doctests`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS). Antes, vamos olhar um código, vai fazer mais sentido antes da explicação:

```
def test() -> None:
    """
    Diz olá ao Anderson.

    >>> test()
    Olá ...
    """
    print("Olá Anderson")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

Dando uma olhada na *docstring* `Olá ...`, você pode tentar ler isso como: "A resposta dessa função vai começar com `Olá`.

Agora voltando a definição é uma continuação do `slice`. Partindo do ponto que "Olá Anderson" tem 12 caracteres. E só passamos o "Olá" (fatia de [0:3]) é como se a validação do iterável fosse feita usando o inicio da *string* sabendo que algo é esperado no final.

Então o `...`, nesse caso seria uma delimitação para que seja feito o assert do inicio do valor produzido (começa com "Olá" e vai '...').

Outro uso legal seria não usar `ELLIPSIS` para delimitar o final, mais o meio ou no inicio: `O...n` ou `... Anderson`. Assim você conseguiria fazer uma assertiva em qualquer parte de qualquer iterável sem descrever o mesmo completamente, partindo do ponto de um intervalo.

Então, nesse caso (*doctests*) podemos simular qualquer saída sem termos que ser muito criteriosos ao pensar no resultado, pois qualquer resposta seria suficiente. Então pense que no escopo das *docstrings* todo retorno obtido por um objeto é o método `__repr__` e a ideia  por traz do `ellipsis` é fazer a assertiva dentro do que for retornado pela representação do objeto.

Algo como:

```
class Anderson:
   pass
```

A classe `Anderson` não tem representação, pois não implementa o método `__repr__`, então seu `print` seria algo como `<__main__.Anderson object at 0x7fa28656c5c0>`, porém a cada execução o valor `0x7fa28656c5c0` não será o mesmo, e para fazer essa validação poderíamos usar `<__main__.Anderson object at ...>` e teríamos certeza do resultado pois o mesmo pode ser validado sem levar em conta o endereço onde a classe foi alocada.

Comment: Um dos usos principais é para omitir  indices em uma dimensão ao acessar matrizes multidimensio Já que vocênais no NumPy. Já que você escreveu essa baita resposta, eu diria que vale a pena pegar um exemplo do uso de Ellipsis no NumPy e colocar aí também.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas ainda acho que é válido adicionar informações. `...`  é usado pelo módulo **pydantic** para expressar atributos de uma model como obrigatórios, mas que podem assumir o valor `None`. Também é usado pelo módulo **fastapi** para tornar obrigatórios os parâmetros de uma função que assumem o valor do tipo `Query`.

Exemplo do **pydantic**:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserModel(BaseModel):
    username: str = Field(...)
    name: str = Field(...)
    email: str = Field(...)
```

Exemplo do **fastapi**:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: str = Query(..., min_length=3)):
    results = {"items": [{"item_id": "Foo"}, {"item_id": "Bar"}]}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q})
    return results
```

[Documentação do fastapi sobre Ellipsis.](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/?h=ellips#make-it-required)

[Documentação do Pydantic sobre Ellipsis.](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#required-fields)